# Most user friendly way to select a time slot when booking a table

Tags: forms, user-behavior, design-patterns, dates, time

I'm designing the **table reservation process** for a website with multiple restaurants.

After selecting the day, **the user has to select the time** of the reservation. The restaurants have multiple shifts (breakfast, lunch, dinner).

I'm exploring different options but each one has some pros and cons and I would love to know your opinion and experience around this.

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: B is confusing, C is obscured. ...A

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Could u elaborate? Obscured?

Comment: Some of the times on option C are not visible due to horizontal overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the options that you shared, I like the **first one** the most. Since for me, it is the most convenient in terms of timing. The time is divided into blocks and it is easy for me to find the right time depending on the part of the day.

On the other hand, I see risks in the absence of custom time. There are times that the user can only select when manually entered (although this depends on the rules of the restaurant).

I would also probably combine the stage of choosing the day and time. So the user will be more convenient monitoring their settings and booking.